# How do I pass a property changed event to an ancestor?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-3.5

I'm sure I am missing some of the basics here so please bear with me.

I have a two objects, a SalesOrder and a SalesOrderLineItem. The lineitems are kept in an `Observablecollection<SalesOrderLineItem>` of SalesOrder, and if I add line items my databound listView knows about the new items.

Now where I am having a problem is here: The SalesOrder has a read only property called "OrderTotal", which knows what the total price from all the line items combined are.

If I change the quantity, or price of a line item, I don't seem to know how to get change notification to bubble up to "OrderTotal".

Both classes inherit from, and fire `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Wham am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ObservableCollection only notifies when an Item is added, removed, or when the list is refreshed, not when a property of an Item within the collection changes.

The SalesOrder class needs to be listening to each SalesOrderLineItem's PropertyChanged event.

-

The OrderTotal property could also be dynamic, generating the total each time...

Comment: This is what I am thinking, but WPF seems to have so much power, that I am wondering if there is a different solution. I'll go with this if not, but I feel like there should be a more elegant way to deal with this.

Comment: Unfortunately I agree with Aaron, you'll have to listen to each SalesOrderLineItem, and to the collection. WPF does have RoutedEvents that bubble, but these only apply in the visual tree; you can't use them in some arbitrary object graph.

Comment: I agree. Binding in WPF is very powerful, and there may be a better way to do this.  You may want to ask your question in a different way.  Right now it leads me to believe you are looking for a way the ObservableCollection will solve this problem. Ask it again more generically-and with diff subject

Comment: Yea, I'm sure I am asking a number of questions wrong. I think for now I will go with this method, and just resolve myself to not knowing what I don't know for now. 3 Months from now I'm sure I will have a much better idea of how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel adventurous, you can try [BindableLinq](http://www.codeplex.com/BindableLinq) or something similar.
It allows you to expose the result of a query that listens to changes.

But it's not out of beta yet, and I'm not sure it will ever be... 
[ContinuousLinq](http://www.codeplex.com/clinq) is another one, but it does not support Silverlight at all yet.

Other than that, you'll have to listen to each child, and add/remove handlers whenever the collection changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<TestClass> List
    {
        get { return _List; }
        set {
            if (_List!= value)
            {
                _List = value;
                raisePropertyChange("List");
                List.ToList().ForEach(i=> i.PropertyChanged+= (o,e)=>
                {
                    //PropertyChanged.Raise(() => List);
        raisePropertyChange("List");
        //or what ever you want
                }
            );


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please done't post the exact same answer to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.

Comment: OK I wont do it again